# invalid or unexpection token, i tried to make my bot discord today, but there this error

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
const Discord = require(‘discord.js’);

const client = new Discord.Client();

var prefix = ‘!’

on(‘message’, message => {

if(message.author === client.user) return;

if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + ‘start’)) {

message.channel.sendMessage(‘Welcome to server);

}

});

client.login(‘TOKEN’);
```

I did these spaces only on this site because it doesn't allow me to post code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I rewrote the code for you so it should work now:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

var prefix = '!'

    client.on('message', message => {

        if (message.author === client.user) return;

        if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'start')) {

            message.channel.send('Welcome to server');

        }

    });

client.login('TOKEN');
```